# pyspark.sql.functions.hash equivalent in .net core c#?

Tags: c#, .net, pyspark

I need to prepare similar hash which is created by pyspark function

> pyspark.sql.functions.hash

Looks like pyspark function uses "Murmur3Hash". Whats the equivalent in c# .net core.
I have tried SHA256 and MD5 both gives different result than pyspark hash function.

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like that .net contains any murmur-hash, so whats left for you is to implement it yourself or find somebody else who has already done it (i.e. finding a package containing murmur-hash). After a quick Google on "Murmur3Hash C#" I found this as the second result: https://github.com/darrenkopp/murmurhash-net with the following description:

> An implementation of the Murmur3 hash for .NET
>
> As of the time this was written, this library supports the 3 main
> Murmur3 variants: 32-bit hash (x86), 128-bit hash (x86) and 128-bit
> hash (x64).

This sounds like what you are looking for, right? The GitHub-readme also contains a link to a signed Nuget-package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/murmurhash-signed/.

Discplaimer: I have not tested the package nor verified that it produces the correct hash. However there is an open-issue on the repo claiming it does not produce the correct hash, so I would verify first if I were you before starting to use it.